# How can I configure the database in the host when I had to change its name there

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, iis, permissions

I have designed a simple cms(well it is not like dnn joomla its simple) and most certainly I have a database where I put my stored procs and tables and I hashed and salted the pwds and so. I sent it to a host using filezilla, everything is alright but one thing: "it doesn't work".

```
System.Exception: Cannot open database "OrganizerDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\D_mydomain.com
```

I have some doubts it might be I had to change the database name because there was already a registered db name there with my db name,I don't know where in the code except my connection strings the db is declared or whatever...its a dilemma...every where in the code i corrected the database but it doesn't work...and I changed the db name in the host cpanel and I even recreated the database using generated scripts and changed it,if any of you professionals could give me a hand here I'd be thankful

Comment: We'll most likely need more information to help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS worker process is running in the context of virtual account (in your case: `IIS APPPOOL\D_mydomain.com`), that account needs access to your database.
If you prefer you can create your own user and make application pool to run under its context, then grant access to database for that user.
More details [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

Quick fix:

1. Create local user myUserName
2. Add this to web.config: `<identity impersonate="true" userName="myUserName" password="myPassword" />`
3. Give required permission to user myUserName on the database